# Is there an OpenSSL function like SSL_CTX_use_*PrivateKey for ECDSA?

Tags: openssl, cryptography, ecdsa

I'm a newcomer to crypto in general and OpenSSL in particular. I'm still in the learning phase, and am looking over the documentation (and even the source code). I see functions called:
SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey
SSL_CTX_use_RSAPrivateKey

But I don't see one called something similar to SSL_CTX_use_ECDSAPrivateKey.

Is there such and function, and just can't find it? Or is ECDSA handled in another manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey` for ECDSA. This function is a generic one for handling all key types. In fact in the forthcoming OpenSSL 3.0, `SSL_CTX_use_RSAPrivateKey` is deprecated and `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey` is the preferred function for all key types including RSA.

In order to use `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey` you need to pass the the key as an `EVP_PKEY` object. If you have the key in the form of an `EC_KEY` object then you can create a new `EVP_PKEY` using `EVP_PKEY_new()` and then assign your `EC_KEY` to it using `EVP_PKEY_set1_EC_KEY` or `EVP_PKEY_assign_EC_KEY`. See:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_PKEY_new.html
https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_PKEY_set1_EC_KEY.html

As an alternative you can use `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file` which will just load the key automatically from the file. Again you can use this function for any key type (including RSA and ECDSA).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I will restart my reading with the material you gave me.